# how to view a datas in table in android

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I saved the edittext value in the sqlite database and I want to view the data from the database in a textview or in a listview when clicking the button how it is possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Button click listener u write the code for getting the all data into one list and then u arrange that list to your listview.

the below code is used for getting the data from sqlite

```
public List<String> selectAll() {
          List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name" },
            null, null, null, null, "name desc");
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));<wbr>
             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          }
          if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
             cursor.close();
          }
          return list;
       }
```

for further inforamtion see the below link

[SQLite in android](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742)